# assign values to GroupID column for rows

Tags: t-sql

The following code generates the rows in the screenshot below.  The goal is to add a new column called `GroupID` that assigns the values shown in blue on the right side of the screen shot.

```
select
*
into #data
from
(
    values
    (157, 84152, 'termination', '7/31/2017'),
    (157, 3025126, 'effective', '8/1/2017'),
    (157, 3025126, 'termination', '8/31/2018'),
    (157, 157, 'effective', '9/1/2018'),
    (1176, 30, 'termination', '5/6/2017'),
    (1176, 1176, 'effective', '5/7/2017'),
    (1176, 1176, 'termination', '11/3/2017'),
    (1176, 30, 'effective', '11/4/2017'),
    (1176, 30, 'termination', '5/6/2018'),
    (1176, 1176, 'effective', '5/7/2018'),
    (1176, 1176, 'termination', '11/9/2018'),
    (1176, 30, 'effective', '11/10/2018'),
    (1176, 30, 'termination', '5/3/2019'),
    (1176, 1176, 'effective', '5/4/2019')
) d (CurrentProducerID, FormerProducerID, DateType, DateValue);

alter table #data alter column DateValue date;

select * from #data;
```

[image]

I have tried using `row_number()` but it does not give the desired result.  Here is my attempt and the outcome:

```
select
*,
--GroupID = row_number() over(partition by CurrentProducerID order by DateValue)
GroupID = row_number() over(partition by CurrentProducerID, FormerProducerID order by DateValue)
from #data;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be the below:-

```
;with ccc as (
select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1)) id from #data
),cte as (
select t1.*,t2.id [t2id] from ccc t1
    left outer join ccc t2 on t2.CurrentProducerID=t1.CurrentProducerID 
                          and t2.FormerProducerID=t1.FormerProducerID
                          and (t2.DateType='termination' and t1.DateType='effective')
                          and (t1.id+1)=t2.id
),cte2 as (
select cte.id,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by CurrentProducerID order by id) [g] from cte where t2id is null
  )
  select cte.CurrentProducerID , cte.FormerProducerID , cte.DateType , cte.DateValue,isnull(cte2.g,cte3.g) g from cte   
    left join cte2 on cte.id=cte2.id
    left join cte2 cte3 on cte.id+1=cte3.id
```

Result will be as below:-

## CurrentProducerID   FormerProducerID    DateType    DateValue   g

```
157                 84152               termination 2017-07-31  1
157                 3025126             effective   2017-08-01  2
157                 3025126             termination 2018-08-31  2
157                 157                 effective   2018-09-01  3
1176                30                  termination 2017-05-06  1
1176                1176                effective   2017-05-07  2
1176                1176                termination 2017-11-03  2
1176                30                  effective   2017-11-04  3
1176                30                  termination 2018-05-06  3
1176                1176                effective   2018-05-07  4
1176                1176                termination 2018-11-09  4
1176                30                  effective   2018-11-10  5
1176                30                  termination 2019-05-03  5
1176                1176                effective   2019-05-04  6
```